# Query about HTML Source tag

Tags: html

My question is what difference does `<source type"video/mp4" src="Boxing1.mp4">` make to: `<source type="video/mp4" src="Boxing1.mp4">`. The difference between the two is '=' is missing after 'type'.

If I leave the '=' out then the video plays in the browser. If I include the '=' then it doesn't play in the browser? I've checked the syntax on W3School.

I'm using Dreamweaver CC (Latest version at this time.)

But Dreamweaver complains: 'Special characters must be escaped :[<]' this happens when I leave the '=' out.

Here's the complete code that I have:

```
<body>
  <video class="background-video" muted autoplay loop>
    <source type"video/mp4" src="Boxing1.mp4">
  </video>
</body>
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

if you leaf the '=' out, your browser ignores the type information "video/mp4" and uses some default, and that seems to work. Figure out the default type for "*.mp4"-Files of your browser (eg. google) and try to use this as type.

Comment: Thanks very much. I'll try that.